# Getting issue while using HibernatePagingItemReader as custom reader

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

Same record is getting retrieved each time however i am expecting to read next item from the reader.

```
@Override
public MyObject read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {          
    HibernatePagingItemReader<MyObject> reader = new HibernatePagingItemReader<>();

    reader.setSessionFactory(taskOracleSessionFactory);
    reader.setQueryString("select t from MyObject t ");
    reader.setPageSize(1);
    reader.setFetchSize(10);
    return reader.read();
}
```

Comment: Need urgent help on it..

Comment: What is your question? What error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

If you call this method every time you need to read something, you always will have the same results, because you re-creating the reader in every method call.

You reader must be created and the method then can be return every time a different record, with something like the following code

```
public void setup() {
    HibernatePagingItemReader<MyObject> reader = new 
    HibernatePagingItemReader<>();

    reader.setSessionFactory(taskOracleSessionFactory);
    reader.setQueryString("select t from MyObject t ");
    reader.setPageSize(1);
    reader.setFetchSize(10);
}

@Override
public MyObject read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
    ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        return reader.read();
    }
```

}

Comment: I tried the suggested thing..Now reader is returning the next item BUT performance is very slow because its fetching all the records each time.    And my application has very amount amount of records that is taking a very long time to get from DB.    Trying to optimize this by using fetch Size ans page Size.   Pls suggest what is the exact/best solution to fetch the records in batch and complete the Reader-Processor-Writer cycle.        It will be very helpful on this point in time.

Comment: I suppose that this job is slow because you read one record at once

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that the application getting so many instances of reader object and no where they were getting closed. Solved it by closing the `HibernatePagingItemReader` after getting data from it.

```
reader.close();
```